# d3 interval.ceil behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

using the example of month.ceil, if we invoke the function against, say,

```
date = new Date (2010, 0, 1)
```

`d3.time.month.ceil` will return itself, while invoking the same function on

```
+date+1
```

the first day of the following month. Perfect.

Question:

Since my data are daily time-series (no time just "YYYY-MM-DD")  when rounding up via ceil I would need to get
the next month even for, say, "2010-01-01", because the event refers to the whole 1st of Jan and not exactly midnight
(as `d3.time.month.ceil(new Date( "2010-01-01"))` would think).

Is there any more robust way to achieve that (besides `+date +1`) that I can use (either in `d3` or anything else)? Something dealing just with dates?

Comment: I'm not clear about the question.  You want to start with a particular date and then calculate the next month from that date?  Or the next day?  If `date` is a Date object then doign `+date+1` is adding one millisecond.  So I'm confused about the intent.

Comment: @ScottCameron in my example `date` is what you see in the definition, i.e. `new Date (2010, 0, 1)`. `+date+1` add a millisecond, as usual, so `ceil` returns the next month and not the current. What I'm asking is: is there a way in d3 (or pure js) to avoid this workaround? Then I said: one way would be dealing with object or pure `date` object instead of datetime (like `new Date`)

Comment: Can you just use a monthly time interval with the `interval.offset` function to add one month (e.g `d3.time.month.offset(date, 1)`)? You would still need to convert your date into a JavaScript date but that shouldn't matter if you're using an interval at the granularity you care about.